# Flask app with Nginx and Gunicorn in Ubuntu

Tags: python, nginx, flask, gunicorn

I have a vps flask application that processes incoming requests and returns a result in the format {result: OK} or {result: BAD}. There is also a bunch of nginx + gunicorn. When only gunicorn works for me, everything works as it should, but as soon as I connect nginx, the server returns me a response in the form of html code, which I will present below.

```
    <html>
<head><title>502 Bad Gateway</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>502 Bad Gateway</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my '/etc/nginx/sites-available/myproject' file:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 0.0.0.0;

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/sammy/myproject/myproject.sock;
    }
}
```

My configurations of myproject.service:

```
[Unit]
Description=Gunicorn instance to serve myproject
After=network.target

[Service]
User=sammy
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/sammy/myproject
Environment="PATH=/home/sammy/myproject/myprojectenv/bin"
ExecStart=/home/sammy/myproject/myprojectenv/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:myproject.sock -m 007 wsgi:app

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

my nginx and myporject status id "active" and have no errors

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong, because I've read a lot of guides and documentation, the result is still unsuccessful

Once again, if I work without nginx, then everything works fine, but I need to connect it too

Comment: What's in the `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/` directory ?

Comment: Same as /etc/nginx/sites-available/myproject. This started working after I changed www-data to root in the nginx.conf file But I don't think this is the right method, so I would like to know what the problem was